# busybox compilation for arm : fatal error: byteswap.h: No such file or directory

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, busybox

Trying to build busybox for ARM architecture

**Error Faced** :

```
> In file included from include/libbb.h:13:0,
>                  from include/busybox.h:8,
>                  from applets/applets.c:9: include/platform.h:157:11: fatal error: byteswap.h: No such file or directory  # include
> <byteswap.h>
>            ^~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. scripts/Makefile.build:197: recipe for target 'applets/applets.o'
> failed make[1]: *** [applets/applets.o] Error 1 Makefile:372: recipe
> for target 'applets_dir' failed make: *** [applets_dir] Error 2
```

**Host Machine** : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

**Target Platform Arch** : ARM

**Tool Chain Used**  : [gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major-linux.tar.bz2](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-rm/7-2017q4/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major-linux.tar.bz2?revision=375265d4-e9b5-41c8-bf23-56cbe927e156?product=GNU%20Arm%20Embedded%20Toolchain,64-bit,,Linux,7-2017-q4-major)

**Busybox** : [busybox-1.27.2.tar.bz2](https://busybox.net/downloads/busybox-1.27.2.tar.bz2)

- Setup cross Compile tool chain and export path
- Download busybox source, configure and build

  $export PATH=$PATH:~/junk/bbb-src-bin/arm7-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/bin

  $make ARCH-arm CROSS_COMPILE=~/junk/bbb-src-bin/arm7-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi- defconfig

  $make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=~/junk/bbb-src-bin/arm7-toolchain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi- install

Answer (score 2):

You are using a compiler that is configured to produce bare metal executables, i.e. ones that run on a system without an operating system, to compile a program that runs on Linux. That's not going to work, at least not without a lot of extra porting effort.

You should use a cross-compiler toolchain, with headers and libraries that support your target operating system.

Comment: It worked for me.      As you suggest, I installed arm cross compiler toolchain Ubuntu 16.04

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev

$ sudo apt-get install gcc make gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi

$ sudo apt-get install binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi

Comment: In other words, you will not be able to run that code on BareMetal/Windows/iOS, when the targeted OS is Linux. As a good workaround for those trying to develop/debug such code: Go for WSL (Windows Subsytem for Linux) to be able to run your code on Windows (WSL)..